Is there a "natural" extension to $(0,\infty)$ of the order-isomorphism $\mathbb{N} \to \{2^a3^b6^{\frac{c}{2}}:a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}_0\}$?
In this question, $\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$, and $\mathbb{N}_0=\mathbb{N}\cup\{0\}$.
Let $f$ be the order-preserving bijection from $\mathbb{N}$ to the set
$$ S:=\{2^a 3^b\sqrt{6}^{\,c} \, : \, a,b,c\in\mathbb{N}_0\}. $$
Is there a "most natural" strictly increasing smooth function $F \colon (0,\infty) \to (0,\infty)$ such that $F(n)=f(n)$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N}$?

Motivation.
As in this question, $S$ nicely illustrates how the Fundamental Theorem of Arithmetic is not trivial: $(S,\times,\leq)$ is "very much like" $(\mathbb{N},\times,\leq)$, in that it is a cancellative commutative ordered monoid that is order-isomorphic to $(\mathbb{N},\leq)$ and has $\min S$ as its identity element; and so in particular, the "factor tree" method that one learns in high school shows that every member of $S$ admits a prime factorisation (where $p \in S$ is "prime" if $p \neq 1$ and there do not exist $x,y \in S \setminus \{1\}$ with $p=xy$). However, prime factorisations are not unique: the prime numbers in $S$ are $2$, $3$ and $\sqrt{6}$, but $2 \times 3 = \sqrt{6} \times \sqrt{6}$.
Now, from a pedagogical point of view, I think this observation becomes more potent when it is phrased in terms of a new multiplication-like structure on $\mathbb{N}$: namely, define the binary operation $\tilde{\times}$ on $\mathbb{N}$ by
$$ m \ \tilde{\times} \ n = f^{-1}(f(m)f(n)). $$
Then $\tilde{\times}$ is in many ways very similar to ordinary multiplication: it has $1$ as a unit, it has prime numbers -- namely $2$, $3$ and $4$ -- and then all the larger numbers are composite numbers built up from multiplying together primes. However,
$$ 2 \ \tilde{\times} \ 4 \ = \ 3 \ \tilde{\times} \ 3 \ = \ 7. $$
Now while it is well-known that FTA is much less trivial than people might assume, what seems less well-known is that the following important corollary of FTA is also much less trivial than people might assume:

A sufficient condition for an expression $\frac{m}{n}$ ($m,n \in \mathbb{N}$) to be in lowest terms is that the only positive integer of which both $m$ and $n$ are multiples is $1$.

(Note: the "lowest-terms expression" of a positive rational number is defined as the expression $\frac{m}{n}$ ($m,n \in \mathbb{N}$) with the smallest possible $m$, or equivalently, with the smallest possible $n$.)
Again, $S$ nicely illustrates the non-triviality of this fact: Let $G=\{\frac{x}{y} : x,y \in S\}$. The value $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$ is a member of $G$, and the numerator $\sqrt{6}$ and denominator $3$ are both prime; and yet $\frac{\sqrt{6}}{3}$ is not in lowest terms, as it can be re-written $\frac{2}{\sqrt{6}}$.
Now what might be nice is if this illustration can be translated into the framework of $\tilde{\times}$, by saying that for integers $m,n \in \mathbb{N}$,
$$ m \ \tilde{\div} \ n \ := \ F^{-1}\Big(\tfrac{f(m)}{f(n)}\Big). $$
Hence my question.
